# Spring WebSocket new handler instead of autowire

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-websocket

Per [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-server-handler), when assigning a handler to a mapping, it is newing a handler instance instead of autowiring. What are the benefits of doing so?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new MyHandler(), "/myHandler")
            .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }
```

If I would like to follow its example, how would I autowire beans to the newly created handler?

EDIT1: I posted the code of 4.2.1, where a bean is actually injected. I meant to post the code of 4.2.2. It has been updated.

Comment: what do mean you by "autowire beans to the newly created handler" ?

Comment: It is calling an `@Bean` method which will inject a bean.

Comment: @Aleson If we manually call `new MyHandler()`, how do we autowire beans in `MyHandler`? I tried `Autowire`, but received `null`, because the newly created instance of `MyHandler` is not Spring managed.

Comment: by declaring it with `@Bean` just like you showed before

Comment: @Aleson Thank you, I must have been confusing myself. On the other hand, do you know what are the advantages of creating a new Handler bean, versus using a Handler singleton? I assume with the new Handler bean approach, each time a new connection is made, a new Handler bean would be made?

Comment: @Aleson Actually, I did a quick test. I created an ArrayList in the Handler, each time a new WebSocket connection is established, its ID is added to the ArrayList. However, even when the Handler is marked as a prototype, I found that the same ArrayList is being reused. Why is this happening?

Comment: friend its hard to give an answer or an opinion about what you asked without looking at the actual implementation of the code,  about your question regarding the advantages of creating spring bean versus using singleton object, you should ask that as a new question to receive more detail explanation

Comment: as to your question about "I assume with the new Handler bean approach, each time a new connection is made, a new Handler bean would be made?" if you declare an object as spring bean, spring will manage the creation of the object with default singleton scope, there are many other scope you can choose depends on your need here is the reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: @Aleson It is already been of much help. Thank you very much. I haven't written much Spring after a long break...